# Who is eligible to receive Zakat. If a man is working is he eligible to receive Zakat Zakat

Tags: zakat

I have a paternal aunt who has two sons both are married and working. One son is a driver. He has Four children all studying. His earnings is falling short to fulfill his families need. Is he eligible for receiving zakat.